# R generating simulated data set with response variables being a function of 2 predictor variables and random variable

Tags: function, dataset, response, simulation, data-generation

I am trying to generate a data set that has the following: a continuous variable (a number between 1 - 10 reflecting animals body size) together with the explanatory variables: season, weather, fish abundance. weather should have no effect on body size (random fill), but season and fish abundance are aimed to be related to body size (the parameters of the distribution of the response are aimed to be a function of 2 predictor variables). Which relation is not so important.. Could be a linear one between body size and fish abundance and similar with season (e.g. in summer highest body size).

I started writing the following code but I dont know how to define that season and fish are related to body size. I could manually define e.g. fill all body sizes bigger than X with summer and all smaller than X with winter etc but I am sure there is a more elegant solution.... Someone has advise?

Here the code I have so far..

`````
y <- seq(0,10, length=400)
index<-dnorm(y, mean=5, sd=2)
index

plot(index)

season <- c("winter", "summer", "spring", "fall")
weather <- c("sun", "storm", "cloudy", "rain")
fishi <-   dnorm(100, mean=50, sd=5)
fishi
x <- seq(0,100, length=400)
fishi<-dnorm(x, mean=50, sd=2)
fishi

data <- data.frame(tern)


emp.data <- data.frame(
  index = index,
  weather = ,
  season = ,
  fishi = )



data <- rep(NA, 400)

for(i in 1:100){
  
  
  data[i] <- 
  
  
}
````

Thanks so much for help!
`````

Comment: You need to work out your distributions and relationships. So say you want 10 fish, n_fish <- 10, then you could draw the body size from (for example) a normal distribution like: rnorm(n_fish,5,1). If you think fish are bigger in summer, you could say that in summer the mean of body size is 7, whereas in autumn it's 5, spring it's 5, and winter it's 3. Same with abundance, how does it affect the mean or sd of the body size distribution? Then make a data.frame with weather, season, abundance values randomly generated in, and predict the body size.

Comment: I am trying to do exactly what you suggest, but I am not sure how to put this into R code. I could write a function saying all fish bigger than 7 get summer, all from 5-7 get spring, etc. but then I have no variation at all, so I don think this is a good solution.. Therefore I could use the code like:
for(i in 1:length(uniq_groups)){
  sub_dat <- subset(dat, size == uniq_groups[I])

How can I do as you say, in summer the mean of body size if 7 (instead of all body sizes in summer are 7).

abundance affects body size positive linear.... the larger the abundance, the larger the body size..

Comment: I think you're the wrong way round. It's not all fish bigger than 7 get summer, it's in summer fish are on average bigger (i.e. mean of 7). So first make a data.frame with your predictor variables df <- data.frame(season = c("Winter","Winter","Summer",etc),weather = c("storm","sun","storm",etc),abundance = c(1,10,4,...)). Then you want to simulate a fish size for each row (observation). E.g. fish_size<-function(season,weather,abundance){if(season == "summer") mean_size = 7; mean_size = mean_size * abundance/100; size = rnorm(1,mean_size,1))}

Comment: Thank you so much this was actually so helpful! I am using now fish_size<-function(season,abundance){
  if(season == "summer") mean_size = 14; 
  if(season == "winter") mean_size = 7; 
  mean_size = mean_size * abundance/64; 
  size = rnorm(length(abundance),mean_size,1)
  return(size)
  }